# Wildcard Query Search Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, wildcard

I am looking to add wildcard ability. Current formula:

```
=query('data set',"select E where B contains '"&B37&"'",0)
```

The issue is that the data set may have slight variation of the referenced cell and I want to accommodate for that.

Comment: You will need to be more specific. For instance, include in your post a list of variations of a specific word or phrase that you would be trying to find with the QUERY.

Comment: convert to upper or lower would help a bit. Like @ErikTyler is saying... how can we responde to this? =query('data set',"select lower(E) where B contains '"&LOWER(B37)&"' label lower(E) '' ",0)

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`=query('data set'!A:E,"select E where LOWER(B) like '%"&LOWER(B37)&"%'",0)` in a separate sheet or from row F in your 'data set' tab. `B37` is where your match criteria is.

...assuming your range on the `'data set'` tab is from `A:E`.

`LOWER(B)` in the query helps to make it case-insensitive. To use a wild card, instead of `contains` use `like` then add the wildcard character `%` inside the single quotes `'%"&LOWER(B37)&"%'`.

You'll need to wrap `LOWER()` around `B37` so that the `LOWER(B)` in the `query` works as expected.